# IF request mapping unresolved AND path not found in static resources location then redirect to index.html

Tags: spring-boot

**The problem (caused by frontend, angularjs context):**

"X uses HTML5 mode in its location service. It means, you will see URLs like www.example.com/mail rather than seeing URLs like this one: www.example.com/#/mail

Also, without following .htaccess rules, you can't access your application directly. So typing www.example.com/mail to the url bar or refreshing your application will cause an Internal Server Error.

Create an .htaccess that stays with the same directory as your index.html and paste the following code inside it:"

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        # Send all requests to the index.html unless
        # it's a directory or a file that actually exists
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

As I am using tomcat this script is as as useful as pseudo code which must be put in Spring Boot application. Otherwise none of the directly typed paths within browser work(get 404 white label server page).

Effectively I need to implement something similar. I can't even figure out which components I should even look at.

So far disjointed pieces of info in my brain:

- Spring filters from filter chain and resources handlers are hit in the order I mentioned them (according to trace logs).
- I need to redirect to index.html whenever the path is:
  A. Not a rest api controller path AND
  B. Not resolved to a static resource within(in my case: 'static' resource folder).

So do I need to create custom resource handler/custom filter? Or maybe problem lies in different dimensions? (tomcat itself?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was more logical than technical:

A. The paths which must resolved by angular js have nothing to do with backed
-> meaning, that backend has no knowledge which paths angular is aware of and which are not.

B. Therefore, if a resource is not resolved by the controllers and resource handlers - this is 404 case for backend. So:

```
@Component
public class WebConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer configurableEmbeddedServletContainer) {
        configurableEmbeddedServletContainer.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
    }
}
```

Resolves the issue. The outcome is that whenever we go to `/mail`, backend returns index.html , then angular resolves the internal path and displays email partial. How angular does it I am not sure myself, I don't know how the html5 model remembers the path.

The shortage of this solution is that request to rest api, targeting wrong rest api path will receive index.html, but status is set so should be no big deal.

**It would nice however to know at which point within the backend flow it is known that the request did not resolve neither to controller neither to static resource and how to capture this behavior.**