# Unable to load second level routing page in vuejs after refreshing it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have my VueJS app running. It is working fine but the only issue is that when I try to refresh the second or third level routing pages, it shows me an error message in the console, stating:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

For eg.,

http://localhost:8080 renders me home page. No issue on refreshing.

http://localhost:8080/details renders details page. No issue on refreshing.

http://localhost:8080/details/users renders users page. On refreshing, it errors out.

I also have similar links defined for http://localhost:8080/details/assets and http://localhost:8080/details/groups which all errors out on page refresh. 
Here is the code for `main.js`:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

import { routes } from './routes';


Vue.use(VueRouter);

//Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes  
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

and for `routes.js`:

```
import Home from './components/summary.vue'
import Details from './components/details/details.vue'
import Users from './components/details/users/users.vue'
import Assets from './components/details/assets/assets.vue'
import Groups from './components/details/groups/groups.vue'

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home},
    { path: '/details', component: Details},
    {path: '/details/users', component: Users},
    {path: '/details/groups', component: Groups},
    {path: '/details/assets', component: Assets}
];
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: `it shows me an error message` do we need to guess what the error message is?

Comment: @JaromandaX: updated the error message. I forgot to include it previously. My bad.

Comment: What server is that? How are you running that server? `npm run dev`?

Comment: yes it is `npm ` only but I am bouncing it by spring boot. But I guess this shouldn't change the behavior of routers.

Comment: this is a server side issue. the routes are only frontend routes and are simply not available on the server. I guess you are not using vue-cli ? if you are able to control the template for the 404 page of this server, the scripts from https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages would help.

Comment: @JacobGoh: I am running vue-cli anyways but I am just not bouncing my Vue server from vue-cli. Otherwise, all components for me are rendered using vue-cli only. What changes would I need to implement in my existing code? Can you elaborate, if possible? And I think this might be a common issue while routing using Vue-JS, so I guess there should be a simple solution as well for this.

Comment: I still don't really understand how your server is working. I don't know how to help. This is a common issue for all Single Page Applications with routing functionality. Simplest way ? Use [hash mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#mode) . Else, this [guide](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) might give you some idea as well

Comment: @JacobGoh My server is running using spring-boot. I have combined my backend apis using spring-boot and using that, I am running my frontend vueJS server as well by mentioning it in maven pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is described in official document of [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)

> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the *history.pushState* API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload

So navigating only in front end will not send request to back end, which is your spring boot application (you can see this from network traffic)

However, when you refresh your page, the request is sent directly to back end, which results the 404 error.

To fix your problem, one option could be setting a default 404 page to `index.html` which is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559592/2428562)

```
@Component
public class WebConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer configurableEmbeddedServletContainer) {
        configurableEmbeddedServletContainer.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you!